# Creating a Report Formula

Tags: reporting, report-formula

Trying to divide the sum of one grouping of Amount by Grand Total Amount, example:

```
Record type: New Biz
Amount 100
Amount 200
Sum = 300
Record type: Existing Biz
Amount 50
Amount 200
Sum = 250
Grand Total Amount = 550
```

How do I get the formula to provide the % of 300/550 for New Biz and % of 250/550 for Existing Biz?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

You can use the PARENTGROUPVAL in a report custom formula to calculate the percentages for each grouping.

AMOUNT:SUM / PARENTGROUPVAL(AMOUNT:SUM, GRAND_SUMMARY)

Does anyone know a good resource for Report formula's?

Comment: Trailhead is always a good place to start, for example:  https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/rd-summary-formulas/rd-compare-groups